# Why my django doesen't show up renders of models from tempates?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to create a Django project site with movies. In templates, I specified the for loop and models.atribute, but they don't show up when I render the page. I created the models via django shell and I will attach the screenshot below.
What is my mistake ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEFQj.png)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> This is the header</h1>

{% for movie in movies %}
    <h1>Test</h1>
<h1>{{ movie.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ movie.description }}</p>
<p>{{ movie.created_date }}</p>

{% endfor %}

<h2>But this is not header</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Views.py

```
def Page(request):
    movies = Movie.objects.all()
    context = {'movie': movies}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Models.py

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    movieid = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150,null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to="../MovieApp/movies/static/img/", default='../img/default-movie.png')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_date"]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: The name of the parameter should be `movies`, not `movie`, so `context = {'movies': movies}`.